Trouble getting object claims using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler in C#
This may be important to note before reading: All this used to work before, using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 6.15.1. After bumping the solution from .net 6.0 to 8.0 and updating that package, it has stopped working. In our staging environment(.net 6.0) it still works as before, and I have tried running that locally, which still works. All the code seems to be the same, and I've tried CTRL+C CTRL+V all the files from our controller down to the functions. I tried downgrading the jwt package, but I have not yet been able to downgrade the entire project to .net 6.0, but that's what I'm currently working on.
This is a hail mary that someone maybe has experienced this before.
In short: The Claims dictionary value is being set to the type of the object, and valueType is the same, whereas before the value was set to a json representation, aswell as the valueType was "JSON"
I have an application that has authentication using JWT.
First, I create the token using a SecurityTokenDescriptor, setting the different fields, then inside I also set Claims to a Dictionary<string,object>.
// ...
 
var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
    {
        // ...
    }),
    Claims = GetClaims(x), //this function returns a Dictionary<string,object>
    // ...
};
_expires = securityTokenDescriptor.Expires;

return jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(
    jwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor)
);


Then I had a function to take a look inside the tokens to see what they contained returning a ClaimsPrincipal:

public ClaimsPrincipal ReturnTokenClaimsPrincipal(string token)
{
    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.SigningKey));
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    return tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = _jwtSettings.Issuer,
        ValidAudience = _jwtSettings.Audience,
        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
        TokenDecryptionKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.EncryptionKey))
    }, out _);
}

However, iterating through the ClaimsPrincipal.Claims, trying to map them to a different object,
like this:
Where the dictionary would contain <DictionaryKey, ClassA> (where ClassA would be same structure as ClassB).

if (claim.Type == "DictionaryKey")
    X.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassB>(claim.Value));


When debugging I found out that the claim.Value is infact not the object itself, but just a string containing something like "Namespace.ClassA".
After downgrading the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to the same version as used in staging, but that did not help(I'm thinking to also try doing that and restarting the machine/Visual Studio to see if it's going through or not)
EDIT: Answer to GHDevOps' question such that it may be formatted
In the first code snippet, where SecurityTokenDescriptor is initialized, at this point:
Claims = GetClaims(x)
The function is (simplified) like this:
public Dictionary<string,object> GetClaims(){
  List<Permissions> somePermissions =
  [
      new Permission
      {
        Name = "SomeName",
        Level = "SomeLevel",
        ExtraInfo = ["A","B","C"]
      }
  ]

  var result = new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
    {
      "DictionaryKey",
       somePermissions
    }
  }
return result;
}


Where and how are you setting the "DictonaryKey" claim to the token?

@GHDevOps In the first code snippet, where SecurityTokenDescriptor is initialized, at this point:
Claims = GetClaims(x)
The function is (simplified) like this:
public Dictionary<string,object> GetClaims(){
List somePermissions =
[
new Permission
{
Name = "SomeName",
Level = "SomeLevel",
ExtraInfo = ["A","B","C"]
}
]
var result = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
{
"DictionaryKey",
somePermissions
}
}
return result;
}

@GHDevOps I updated the main post with the same comment, where it is formatted readably :)
